# Rails vendor asset templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I was wondering if there was a good solution for getting vendor `html` templates into the rails asset pipeline.  Right now I'm making it work by putting the two templates I need in `/public`

I used Bower to install `angular-ui-bootstrap` and I can require the javascript fine from application.js after adding the `config.assets.path` in `application.rb`.

How do you do the same for the html templates that the angular module needs?  The JS is in `/src`, the template is in `/template`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question. You can add them as template strings js in assets/javascripts but it could get a little messy.